# LESS conditional import

Tags: import, less, conditional-statements

I basically need this:

```
html[dir="ltr"]{
    @import "ltr.less";
}
html[dir="rtl"]{
    @import "rtl.less";
}
```

But it throws an error.

How can I import different files based on a CSS selector?

Comment: Usually it's useful to mention the exact error you get and what tool you use to convert Less to CSS. AFAIK, your snippet works with reference Less compiler (since v1.5 or so). Note however that this code won't do what you probably expect it to: in fact, there's no "conditional import" there, both files will be always imported and their contents put into the corresponding `html` tag (i.e. `html[dir=...]` will prepend every selector in imported files).

Comment: The error is that it doesn't read the imported files and returns a definition error on a mixin I am using (because it's defined in the imported file.)

Comment: So you're saying this isn't the way to do a conditional import. Is there another way to acoomplish this? I want a different file imported depending on the value of the dir attribute.

Comment: Note that Less has no idea of the HTML page you will apply the resulting CSS to, so with Less it's impossible to "conditionally" do anything based on values of HTML attributes or similar stuff.